# How to stop a while loop if the user entered a special character

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in java and I'm getting some numbers from the user and I wanna say if the user entered '#' exit the while loop.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: break; next time please search the web for 5 seconds. you'll find the answer easy enough

Comment: .equals("#") == true is a useful information too.

Comment: @JackTools.Net why compare a boolean to true?

Comment: If I had found the answer I wouldn't bother myself to be insulted by people like you user2717954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have gotten the user input, you can see if the input equals "#" like so:

```
input.equals("#");
```

You can get the user input using Scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
```

You can break from a loop by using break.

The while loop would look like this:

```
while (true) {
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("#")) {
        break;
    }

    int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To terminate any kind of loop, you use a [`break` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String entrada="a";
while(!entrada.equals("#")){
        System.out.println("hola");
        entrada = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use break to stop your loop

```
string userInput = "sdfss £sdf";

while(true)
{
   if(userInput.matches("[^ \w]"))
   {
     break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use while loop here to terminate if user enter -1 and get the total of user input numbers

```
while(true){
    System.out.print("Input the number  :"); 
    int number = input.nextInt();
    if(number >=0)
    total += number;
    if(number == -1)
        break;
}

System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```